# C 2D Arrays removing certain predetermined rows by shifting the ones below it

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

This is my first post here.

An assignment of my online course in C asked me to remove each row in a real(non dynamically allocated, pointers are not used) whose *average sum* is greater than the average sum of the whole matrix. The rows should be "removed" by shifting the ones below it up by one position.

I have set up a matrix with the following code:

`int matrix[100][100]`

Now, my idea was to create a regular 1D array which **stores the *indexes* of the rows to-be-removed**.

This is how I did it:

```
k = 0;                                                    
for (i = 0; i < no_of_rows; i++) {                        
  average_sum_of_row = 0;                                 
  for (j = 0; j < no_of_columns; j++) {                   
    average_sum_of_row += matrix[i][j];                   
  }                                                       
  average_sum_of_row = average_sum_of_row / no_of_columns;

  if (average_sum_of_row > average_sum_of_matrix) {       
    indexes_of_rows_to_remove[k] = i;                     
    k++;                                                  
    l++;                                                  
  }                                                       
}
```

Which works just fine! I get an array whose elements are the indexes of the rows which need to be removed. However, while implementing my code into the following:

```
m = 0;                                     
for (i = 0; i < V; i++) {                  
  if (indexes_of_rows_to_remove[m] == i) { 
    for (k = i; k < no_of_rows - 1; k++) { 
      for (j = 0; j < no_of_columns; j++) {
        matrix[k][j] = matrix[k + 1][j];   
      }                                    
    }                                      
    i--;                                   
    no_of_rows--;                          
  }                                        
  m++;                                     
}
```

It does not work. What I used is my existing code of removing a row by shifting the ones below it up and decreasing the number of rows by one, but this simply doesn't work and I don't know why.

I tried using a separate integer(m) to go through all elements of the array of indexes, but for some reason it does not work.

Thanks all!

Comment: Your deletion algorithm won't work if you store the rows to be deleted. Ie: When you delete the row from the matrix your previously stored indexes will become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this algorithm, which skips the rows to be deleted:

```
k = 0
For i in number of rows:
  If i not to be deleted:
    matrix[k] = matrix[i] # copy the whole row here
    k++
```

The algorithm you are trying to implement is complicated and very inefficient.

Comment: I am sure I am missing something here, but what do you mean by "skipping" the rows that need to be deleted? As I understand it, I should create only one loop which if the row "i" doesn't need to be deleted copies the row "i" to row "k"? Did I get it?

Comment: Yes exactly. I meant if i needs to be deleted don't copy (skip) but it's not clear I agree.